# Youtube video sometimes returns not available

Tags: wordpress, youtube

On a wordpress website we are showing some video's on product pages.
Without any regularity there is a "video not available" message. I was hoping we could get some help figuring out any way this is possible. Below is the error we are getting, which doesnt provide a lot of inofrmation.

I already kind of ruled out the copyright to be the issue, since this is not constantly and happens at random moment & intervals.

`"debug_error": "{\"errorCode\":\"auth\",\"errorDetail\":\"0\",\"errorMessage\":\"Deze video is niet beschikbaar\",\"yk\":\"\",\"xI\":\"0;a6s.0\",\"aB\":2}",`

Comment: With which video(s), exactly you're getting this response? - consider check the "console" tab of F12 developer tools in your browser and check if additional info is shown there...

Answer (score 0):

I've had to debug this issue for a week since it happened so randomly. No idea what causes it, but what I did to get around it was altering the onReady event function to check the errorCode, and then stop the video before we call the play event.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    var data = event.target.playerInfo.videoData;
    if (data.errorCode == "auth") {
        event.target.stopVideo();
    }
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

onPlayerReady is what we call on the onReady event, as in options.events.onReady.
This only does the check once, since I did not want to hammer Youtube if a video doesn't load.

It is a very aggravating problem and I can't seem to find any more info on it either. An auth error would point to something authentication related, but we get this with videos we own and specifically enabled for embedding, and as far as I know the iframe api does not require any api keys to use.